# Android: Lock an apk file

Tags: android, locking, apk

I want to lock my installed app to backup .apk file (from apps like Astro file manager) so that others don't use my drawable/assets by converting .apk to .zip file.

Can you please let me know if there is any way to do that?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do what you want to do, as far as I know! Instead, you can use [Progaurd](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to obfuscate your code to make it unreadable.

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the proguard tool provided in sdk..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to obfuscate resources with Proguard tool, here brother DexGuard, obfuscate only constant string on code. The way then I use to obfuscate assets, as configuration files of application is encrypt it with AES128 or AES256, before generate an apk file. And, on application desencrypt the assets when I want use. For example, I have one configuration file on my app (app.config), instead of save the raw content as:

```
{
  "endpoint": "http://some.host.com",
  "username": "user",
  "password": "pass"
}
```

I save there content encrypted with AES:

```
E4B07406CBE2C89A8083D133638C945395950745A16702951FFC48B
```

And when i want load a configuration, I desencrypt it, and parse a JSON text.